# Appending item on same index

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have these indexes: [3,1,1,2] which shows position for every element in the first list
And I need to append these items to that corresponding indexes:

```
first_list = [Item("beer", 4), Item("steak", 1), Item("hamburger", 1), Item("donut", 3)]
```

to list, to be like in this particular order, so after the item is inserted on the index and the next item is again pointing to the same position, the first added moves to next the index and a new item is inserted to right position.

```
   [ Item("hamburger", 1),Item("steak", 1), Item("donut", 3),Item("beer", 4)]
```

I need this algorithm to work in bigger lists so this is just an example.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How does the list of indexes relate to this result?

Comment: Indexes for each item in list, where it needs to lay in new list

Comment: So this is basically a priority queue where the "indices" indicate the priority?

Comment: You have index 1 twice, so why isn't `Item("steak", 1)` duplicated in the result?

Comment: Every item in list have its index in indexes, but when the index is already used, it needs to shift the new array

Comment: If you could clearly explain how this works, you could probably write the code to do it.

Comment: Yes but i could not think the solution so i asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following builds a priority queue, where the "indices" indicate the priority of each item:

```py
>>> indices = [3, 1, 1, 2]
>>> items = [("beer", 4), ("steak", 1), ("hamburger", 1), ("donut", 3)]
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> prio = []
>>> new = []
>>> for i, item in zip(indices, items):
...     index = bisect_left(prio, i)
...     prio.insert(index, i)
...     new.insert(index, item)
... 
>>> new
[('hamburger', 1), ('steak', 1), ('donut', 3), ('beer', 4)]
```

Comment: Where is the `[3, 1, 1, 2]` list used?

Comment: Yes, but because hamburger is after steak, it needs to be before as it have again 1 index but newer

Comment: I think the `hamburger` coming before `steak` in the output example is a mistake because `steak` should have been inserted first.

Comment: Yes, but this is the right answer, and other test cases uses the same logic

Comment: @ToklCz See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but import are prohibited

Comment: @ToklCz The standard library exists to be used, so you should use it. Anything else is nonsense.

Comment: "import are prohibited" - `bisect` is one of the modules that is installed together with Python, is this a home assignment or something?

Comment: Yes, it is home assignment :d

Comment: @ToklCz [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/bisect.py#L68) is the source code for `bisect_left`, so you can just copy it into your script if that really helps.